# Django filter returning duplicates after order_by based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, django

I'm having difficulty returning unique `Clazz` objects based off my criteria and ordering. `Clazz` and `Session` are two separate models and a class can have many sessions.

Once I introduced the `order_by` I'm seeing duplicate `Clazz` objects. How can I remove the duplicates? A simple `distinct()` doesn't seem to work.

```
classes = Clazz.objects.filter(location=loc).distinct().order_by('session__start_date', 'session__end_date')
```

Comment: If you order by attributes on the `Session` model, and a class has multiple sessions, then it will appear in the queryset once for each session. This is the [documented behaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) (see the note). See also [ticket 18165](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18165). You can't simply return each `Clazz` only once - what related `session` would you use?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do something like this:

```
classes = Clazz.objects.filter(location=loc).annotate(
        startdate=Max('session__start_date'),
        end_date=Max('session__end_date')
    ).order_by('startdate', 'end_date')
```

Answer (score 0):

After @Alasdair's response, ended up just doing this:

```
dup_list = []
class_list = []
for c in classes:
    if c not in dup_list:
        dup_list.append(c)
        class_list.append(c)
classes = class_list
```

Comment: Did you every try `classes = Clazz.objects.filter(location=loc).order_by('session__start_date', 'session__end_date').distinct()`?

Comment: Yes, same thing happens as above